# office365 をメールサーバしたoutlook2013 の pop3 受信が間欠的ですが、異常に遅くなりました。原因究明はどうするといいのでしょうか？

Tags: mail

症状がでてから、下記のチェックをしましたが、原因不明です。２日ほどたって、症状はなくなりました。

１．マイクロソフト(office365) に問い合わせるが現象はでていないとの回答
２．ネットで調べても、現象がでているつぶやきなし。
３．セキュリティソフトを切っても変化なし。

なお、pop3 pops （ＳＳＬ通信です。）

これ以外にチェックする点はあるでしょうか？　症状が発生したＰＣは、２０台弱です。windows7 windows10 が混在です。

ルータには、特定のＰＯＲＴに制限かける機能はないです。

Answer (score 1):

まず、現時点で現象が起きていないのであれば何が起きていたのかを事後的に調べるのはほぼ不可能です。

質問に書かれている内容だけでは情報が少なすぎて調べる方向性すら示すことができません。初歩的に確認できるのはLANケーブルの接続間違えてループしていないか、ぐらいでしょうか。

まぐれ当たりに期待するのでなければ、それなりの準備をしたうえで現象が起きるのを待ち切り分けをしていくしかありませんので、知識のある業者さんに依頼されることをおすすめします。